# Use different time-field name with mutiple mappings in ElasticSearch index

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, kibana

I setted up an **MongoDB, ElasticSearch 1.7.2 & Kibana 4.1.2 stack** in order to visualize reports from Mongo collections. I am using **Mongo-Connector** in order to populate Elastic Search index from Mongo Redolog.

My setup :

- A **MongoDB** database 'DB' with 2 collections 'Col1' and 'Col2' (which have respectively 'createdAt' and 'startDate' time fields)
- **Mongo-Connector** set an ElasticSearch index named 'DB' with 2 mappings : 'Col1' and 'Col2'. Data are accessible using the following ElasticSearch API route : http://localhost:9200/DB/Col1/_search.

I configured the DB index and use 'createAt' (from Col1 Mongo data collection) as the Time-field name in Kibana Indices panel.

I want to **visualize a bar chart** on 'Col2' and **filter using a specific date range** on 'Col2'>'startDate' time field.

**My questions :**

1. Is it possible to use startDate as the filter ? I saw on the _msearch generated ElasticSearch request that the filter is the Time-field setted for this index (i.e. createdAt). I found a workaround by specify the 5 last years for the createdAt in order to not restrict my data range on this time field value.
2. Can I modify these fields in the exported JSON formatted ES request and reimport it?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Do not hesitate to ask for additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found myself a solution.

You just have to specify the **source and destination namespace set** as **mongo connector** command line arguments :

> mongo-connector -m bdd.myhost.fr:27017 -t reporting.myhost.fr:9200 -d
>   elastic_doc_manager --auto-commit-interval=0  --namespace-set
>   DB.Col1,DB.Col2 --dest-namespace-set DB_Col1.Col1,DB_Col2.Col2

Answer (score 0):

Each Kibana index pattern is tied to one date field.  So, to use a second date field, you need to use a second index pattern.

I've seen people do "logstash-YYYY.mm.dd" and then also have "logstash-*".

It might also be possible with index aliases.